# Magento 2 UI form Multiple image upload

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have implemented multiple image upload using the following code.

```
   <field name="press_images">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">press_images</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="isMultipleFiles" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="pressfeature/image/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

I used https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-sample-imageuploader way to upload images. The image uploading works fine. When you browser the image and choose it. Then a controller gets fired which uploads all images in temp folder using an ajax call. When i click save button the image data and other data is send correctly.

My question is how should i save this filename in database so when i click edit i should see both images in edit form.

Comment: This is custom image? where you want to save it? in custom table?

Comment: Only the name of the file but the file will be moved from tmp directory to <module media> directory.

Comment: But where you want to insert filename in DB?

Comment: Yes in database.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution, Changes need to dataProvider file.

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getDefaultImage()) {
            $img['default_image'][0]['name'] = $item->getDefaultImage();
            $img['default_image'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl()."/".$item->getDefaultImage();
            $fullData = $item->getData();
            $this->_loadedData[$item->getId()] = array_merge($fullData, $img);
        }
        else {
            $this->_loadedData[$item->getId()] = $item->getData();
        }
    }
    return $this->_loadedData;
}
```

FROM THIS

```
$img['default_image'][0]['name'] = $item->getDefaultImage();
$img['default_image'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl()."/".$item->getDefaultImage();
```

TO THIS

```
$img['default_image'][$i]['name'] = $item->getDefaultImage();
$img['default_image'][$i]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl()."/".$item->getDefaultImage();
```

where $i is the number of image uploaded. save all file names in an array in database.